# Make back button go to a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to JavaScript, or JQuery (or any plug in actually) to force the browser to load a specific page when the back button is clicked.

Basically insert a page into the browser's history.

I've found a way of doing it below, but it seems long winded. Am I missing something?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Back button test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         window.history.pushState('other.html', 'Other Page', 'other.html');
         window.history.pushState('initial.html', 'Initial Page', 'initial.html');
    </script>

    Initial page <br />

    <script type="text/javascript">

         window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
            if(document.URL.indexOf("other.html") >= 0){
                document.location.href = document.location;
            }
         });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't modify the history of a browser, this is a major security feature.  If you've found a way around it, that might work well for you, but keep in mind it might upset people.  I know if I was on a site that hijacked the back button, I wouldn't be back.  Instead, use better UX to give the user links.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the comment. +1 for the info mate :) It's not a public facing site, but that would explain why it's been difficult to do. Hmmm...

Comment: Thanks for the answer MaddHacker. I got a lot of down votes, but not so much information on why it shouldn't be done, or any suggested alternatives... kind of disappointing, but thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: No problem, you probably got downvoted because it's seen as a rather questionable practice.  I can understand your frustration though, best of luck!